# TypeScript infer optional generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm way out of my depth. I want to do an inference of a generic that has an optional "parse" function which in turn returns the formatted value [or throws].

Code says more than a thousand words, so here it goes:

```
export type RouteDefInput<TInput = unknown> = {
  parse: (input: unknown) => TInput;
};
export type RouteDefResolver<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = (opts: { ctx: TContext; input: TInput }) => Promise<TOutput> | TOutput;

export type RouteDef<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = {
  input?: RouteDefInput<TInput>;
  resolve: RouteDefResolver<TContext, TInput, TOutput>;
};

export type inferRouteInput<
  TRoute extends RouteDef<any, any, any>
> = TRoute['input'] extends RouteDefInput<any>
  ? ReturnType<TRoute['input']['parse']>
  : undefined;

const context = {};
function createRoute<TInput, TOutput>(
  route: RouteDef<typeof context, TInput, TOutput>,
) {
  return route;
}

function stringParser(input: unknown): string {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    return input;
  }
  throw new Error('not a string');
}

const myRoute1 = createRoute({
  input: {
    parse: stringParser,
  },
  resolve({ input }) {
    return {
      output: input,
    };
  },
});

const myRoute2 = createRoute({
  resolve({ input }) {
    return {
      output: input,
    };
  },
});

// this should render MyRouteInput1 as "string"
type MyRouteInput1 = inferRouteInput<typeof myRoute1>;

// this should render MyRouteInput2 as "undefined" (works)
type MyRouteInput2 = inferRouteInput<typeof myRoute2>;
```

How could I properly make the `inferRouteInput` to work both of these two cases?

I've bashed my head on this for tooo long - here's playground link if you'd like to play: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKECuNgBFgBmAkgHZjYA8AKqefALxyYkDWJEA7iQHxyMDeAKDhwwAQygBnYAC44ACgCWZbHOZtOJAJR9eNFTADcggL7HQkWAmSoM2PITTBJEADYA3YFArC4VAMIQJDggDEys7FwANL76dHzhGtGxAPLY8YzqkSSCvIzyEGAwknL8cADGMCByAUEhRnDKdDW02HAmOvS8AApQEAC2itLUaTB0vAA+fqN0xoIW0PBIKOhYOPgEPiK1waBhWZox2637EYep6W2ZZ1y5CUIiTdgA-HJ264Qn1CfcxiJQzjcnjeawcBCcLg8XmogV2oSifhOCKoM2wv1McwWVmWqGUBC872AX1ihLge2AJAAJpJVvYNhQxCREAjGcy4KzuHdGFRCQBtADkTxg-IAumTQhTqbSPsQDAymZyRM90MAYJgoCQqDZqHzBQZRQLxFJgKLFXA1FTCMpgJS5uUgpJ4Pa4WF+GZBARmJVFEEKgCxDhCd8DMjUTBuPJfH17CC6YQKDiIAQKnU9sikdNLuGYjoHnAAWqNfnQcYTIIPV6YD6SHBHVBlABzboSaRQJQGC1JbRyOuNuB5xTJ+SJ5NCvj0Rj83skBv83O+f6q9U1oV-dq+GAACz6HDgJGAu4AolA+m3+ex4GJazB6zO56Xy87HXB+ohCQBGBLlf2B0HyAcdv2C6iC2sjXreTagVARztDBAKQp4-6NAY7TziIi6FjWeboXAazNMhdAwSI7rETEHR2g68CvoSABMX4-sAhL-lGgJQkhY4dEBOEFsuXE4bhWZyEKRHtGuJhkVocwAPRSQgm5DLWm5YK4lL5pKXhwAAsm+oInJ+Yg0gARNODaGYIOJaTp9h6QkeIErpcoji+Vk4O+6KCDJckKZISmYCpamWlAlmEicdEGXAhnMJSVr7pShkKBw0AsJIWjmTYwUOXQdGMHZUAhY5NhJs5tHokAA

Thanks a million!

Any links to good reading on this subject or on TypeScript generics in general is also appreciated as I struggle to find good sources to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
export type RouteDefInput<TInput = unknown> = {
  parse: (input: unknown) => TInput;
};
export type RouteDefResolver<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = (opts: { ctx: TContext; input: TInput }) => Promise<TOutput> | TOutput;

export type RouteDef<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = {
  input?: RouteDefInput<TInput>;
  resolve: RouteDefResolver<TContext, TInput, TOutput>;
};

export type inferRouteInput<
  TRoute extends RouteDef<any, any, any>
> = TRoute extends RouteDef<any, infer TInput, any>
  ? NonNullable<TInput>
  : undefined;

const context = {};
function createRoute<TInput, TOutput>(
  route: RouteDef<typeof context, TInput, TOutput>,
) {
  return route;
}

function stringParser(input: unknown): string {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    return input;
  }
  throw new Error('not a string');
}

const myRoute1 = createRoute({
  input: {
    parse: stringParser,
  },
  resolve({ input }) {
    return {
      output: input,
    };
  },
});

const myRoute2 = createRoute({
  resolve({ input }) {
    return {
      output: input,
    };
  },
});

// this should render MyRouteInput1 as "string"
type MyRouteInput1 = inferRouteInput<typeof myRoute1>;

// this should render MyRouteInput2 as "undefined" (works)
type MyRouteInput2 = inferRouteInput<typeof myRoute2>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. The solution was a bit brute force — overloading the `createRoute` function. Here's what I have:

```
export type RouteDefInput<TInput = unknown> = {
  parse: (input: unknown) => TInput;
};
export type RouteDefResolver<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = (opts: { ctx: TContext; input: TInput }) => Promise<TOutput> | TOutput;

// export type RouteDef<
//   TContext = unknown,
//   TInput = unknown,
//   TOutput = unknown
// > = {
//   input?: RouteDefInput<TInput>;
//   resolve: RouteDefResolver<TContext, TInput, TOutput>;
// };

export type RouteDefWithInput<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = {
  input: RouteDefInput<TInput>;
  resolve: RouteDefResolver<TContext, TInput, TOutput>;
};

export type RouteDefWithoutInput<
  TContext = unknown,
  TInput = unknown,
  TOutput = unknown
> = {
  resolve: RouteDefResolver<TContext, TInput, TOutput>;
};
export type RouteDef<TContext = unknown, TInput = unknown, TOutput = unknown> =
  | RouteDefWithInput<TContext, TInput, TOutput>
  | RouteDefWithoutInput<TContext, TInput, TOutput>;

export type inferRouteInput<
  TRoute extends RouteDef<any, any, any>
> = TRoute extends RouteDef<any, infer Input, any> ? Input : never;

const context = {};
function createRoute<TInput, TOutput>(
  route: RouteDefWithInput<typeof context, TInput, TOutput>,
): RouteDefWithInput<typeof context, TInput, TOutput>;
function createRoute<TInput, TOutput>(
  route: RouteDefWithoutInput<typeof context, TInput, TOutput>,
): RouteDefWithoutInput<typeof context, TInput, TOutput>;
function createRoute(route: any) {
  return route;
}

function stringParser(input: unknown): string {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    return input;
  }
  throw new Error('not a string');
}

const myRoute1 = createRoute({
  input: {
    parse: stringParser,
  },
  resolve(input) {
    return {
      output: input,
    };
  },
});

const myRoute2 = createRoute({
  resolve({ input }) {
    return {
      output: input,
    };
  },
});

// this should render MyRouteInput1 as "string"
type MyRouteInput1 = inferRouteInput<typeof myRoute1>;

// this should render MyRouteInput2 as "unknown" (works)
type MyRouteInput2 = inferRouteInput<typeof myRoute2>;
```

Comment: This breaks the inference on `resolve({ input })`